# What's a "drop-in activity"?

Tags: phrases

What are "drop-in activities"? I often run across this phrase while reading about museums, recreation centers etc.

Comment: Be careful not to confuse a 'drop-in activity', with a 'drop in activity'! The latter occurs during times of economic recession.

Comment: *cf.* **Walk-in interview,** "job screening that happens without an appointment."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merriam-Webster defines  [drop-in](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drop-in)  as:

> a casual visit or brief stop

So a drop-in activity is an activity that does not require any booking or appointment. You can participate in the activity on a casual visit. For example, the Minnesota Children's Museum offers a drop-in "Paint Your Own Face" activity. No sign-ups are required. Walk in with your child; walk out with Winnie the Pooh or the Joker.

Answer (score 0):

[Drop-in](http://dictionary.infoplease.com/drop-in):

> - Informal.a social gathering at which the guests are not expected to stay long: Be sure to stop by our house for a glass of eggnog at our Christmas drop-in.

The expression is quite common  in the context of recreational activities:

> - The Student Recreation Center *is open for drop-in recreation and activities*all hours the building is open. Exceptions are made for special events and advanced notice is given when possible. All hours are subject to change based on event scheduling in the Student Recreation Center.

Source:http://dictionary.infoplease.com/drop-in